# Why is this question "too localized"?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons, closed-questions

I am aware that [this question about escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150403/how-to-echo-php-stringvariable-containing-special-characters) is slobby, and probably also a duplicate. But, I think, it is a valid question. It has a correct and marked-as-useful answer too. Why was it closed as "too localized"?

Comment: I would vote to close as unclear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the problem with "too localized" was that it was just too easy to apply to practically anything that wasn't asked very well. This is another example of that.

I was able to make sense of the question, I edited it - it's a duplicate of about 100 other duplicates that probably duplicate 50 more respectively, but it wasn't too localized.

The issue is, by saying "This is unlikely to help anyone in the future" - we weren't really telling people what's *wrong* with the question, and in today's case "unclear what you're asking" would have been appropriate to the first version of it.

I'll leave it up to folks with privileges to decide what to ultimately do with it, I recommend either marking it as a duplicate, or just letting it walk out into that good night ...